# How to change the icon of apk file after phonegap build

Tags: cordova, apk, phonegap-build

I have converted my website to android app using phonegap build. I want to know how to change the icon and the app name. I tried to unzip the apk file and changed the icon from res folder, but when I try to install after reconverting to apk, the app is not installed on my device.

Comment: Inside your congig.xml of the phonegap project ,there must be a <name> tag , specify the name of your app there , then inide the <Widget> tag add the icon to point to correct location , ex '<icon src="www/img/icon/fnb_logo.png" />' . And yes build your phonegap and then install on phone. You cannot just make change to .apk file .After build changing icon or app name is not possible.Hope it helps

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to change the icon before building the app instead of trying to figure it out later on.

Currently, it's "out of the box"